# soda and chrome browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-rc

How to run chrome in selenium [soda test](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda)?

When I set `browser: "chrome"` it opens firefox anyway.

```
browser = soda.createClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 4444,
    url: "http://localhost:3000",
    browser: "chrome"
 });
```

This method dont even executes:

```
browser = soda.createClient({
   host: "localhost",
   port: 4444,
   url: "http://localhost:3000",
   browser: "custom /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, use `googlechrome` instead of `chrome`

```
var soda = require('soda');

var browser = soda.createSauceClient({
  'url': 'http://yourwebsite/'
, 'username': ''
, 'access-key': ''
, 'os': 'Windows 2003'
, 'browser': 'googlechrome'
, 'max-duration': 300
});
```

See http://learnboost.github.io/soda/ for more details. In fact, the example I have provided is from their website. Also, you could try *chrome or *google, since that seems to be **[supported functionality](https://github.com/testingbot/soda/blob/master/test/client.test.js#L13).**